# Inno setup wait untill installed (cmd script)

Tags: cmd, inno-setup

I have a little problem with inno setup combine with cmd. I have made a cmd script to install Sql server 2012 with a configurationfile. So in inno setup i run this cmd script to instal Sql server but it doesnt wait untill the instal is completed (obviously because the cmd only has the task to run Sql.exe with some parameters). Does anyone have a smart solution to make it "wait" for SQL to be installed?

Greetings, Chris

CMD

```
START "" "C:\Program Files\B4ict\IQ-Soft\SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /CONFIGURATIONFILE="C:\Program Files\B4ict\IQ-Soft\ConfigurationFile.ini"
```

Inno setup?

```
Filename:  "{app}\SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe"; Parameters: /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /CONFIGURATIONFILE=C:\Program Files\B4ict\IQ-Soft\ConfigurationFile.ini; ?
```

---

Comment: Err, run that tool directly from Inno Setup, with no CMD script ? This, I'd say, is the most frequently asked question. People are creating batch scripts running them through the command prompt blaming Inno Setup (that's not your case; no offense at all, please do not take this personally ;-) It makes me wonder why. Are you 100% sure that you need to have that CMD script ?

Comment: well the CMD script run's the sql instal with the config. For some reason i cant get inno-setup to work with the parameters that i need. But it does work within a cmd script. Ill add the cmd script in the question u might know how to help with that :p

Comment: If you run the (cmd) standalone (manually), does it wait for the installer to finish? I.e. does the console window disappear only after the installation finishes or immediately?

Comment: Try this `Filename: "{app}\SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe"; Parameters: "/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /CONFIGURATIONFILE=""{app}\ConfigurationFile.ini"""`. You missed to escape the path for the `/CONFIGURATIONFILE`.

Comment: TLama could i ask u an other question?is it possible to skip the part of the installer where u give a target location and the page where you create the shortcut?

Comment: To disable the page where the user enters the application directory, set the `DisableDirPage` directive to `no`. To disable the page where the user enters the start menu folder name set the `DisableProgramGroupPage` directive to `no`. And finally, to notify users on Stack Overflow prepend `@` char before their names (like e.g. @TLama to notify me). We don't need to do that because you are the post owner and as such you are always notified ;-)